# Disable prompt for parameters in Azure ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Is it possible to disable the prompt for missing parameters during deploy/verify of ARM template, to make it fail if one was not provided in parameter template/template?

UPDATE
Yes, using powershell and automating it.

Comment: can you provide a little more information on your situation, is this portal, powershell, cli? are you looking to automate? If a parameter isn't provided either by default value, or template file then the deployment would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about Azure Powershell\Cli? No, there is no such an option.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermresourcegroupdeployment?view=azurermps-6.4.0#required-parameters
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-deployment-create

By design these utilities will prompt for a parameter if its missing

Comment: Also using test version of the ps function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/test-azurermresourcegroupdeployment?view=azurermps-6.4.0) but that doesnt support either.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Az PowerShell, the the answer is yes. Use the `-SkipTemplateParameterPrompt` flag to cause the deployment to error out instead of a prompt. [See the Az PowerShell docs for New-AzResourceGroupDeployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-2.5.0)

Comment: Just posted feature request for the [Azure CLI](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11972)